# How do I link the route to the component using vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to use vue-router to link url's to their corresponding components.

My issue is that only the root url ('/') can link to the correct component and any other url (e.g. '/first') does not link to their component. All of them link to the component which belongs to  the '/' url.

When I use "a" tag in the vue file it will route to the right component - it's only when I input the url directly into the browser that it doesn't work

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router/index.js'

Vue.use(ElementUI)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  // components: { App },
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '../components/Hello.vue'
import First from '../components/firstPage.vue'
import Login from '../components/logIn.vue'

Vue.use(Router)


const routes =[
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path:'/first',
    component:Hello
  }
]
const router = new Router({
  routes
})
export default router
```

Comment: You must be using `your_url/first`. Try using `your_url/#/first.`

Comment: it works! thank you very much. Does it mean all of my urls should be like `my_url/#/a/b/c?` it has a # between my_url and the relative url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can also try as below. It's works, just try it! You can add `mode: 'hash',` to give default `#` in all `urls`.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '../components/Hello.vue'
import First from '../components/firstPage.vue'
import Login from '../components/logIn.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'hash',
   base: '/your_base_name_if_you_want',
   linkActiveClass: 'active-tab', //if you w
   routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/if_you_want_to_redirect',
        name: 'Login',  //Whatever
        component: {
            render (c) { return c('router-view'); }
        },

        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: Login
                name: 'Login',
                meta: { title: 'Your title name' }
            },
            {
                path:'/first',
                component:Hello
                name: 'Hello',
                meta: { title: 'Your title name' }
            }
        ]
    }
]
})

export default router
```

You can also remove it from your `urls` using:

```
var router = new VueRouter({
    history: true
});
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode

This is why you can't get the 'Hello' component when your url is '/first'. Instead you can try input '/#/first'.
If you want to use history mode like '/first', set the mode attribute for your route object like this.

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

Hope it helps you.